# A library for C# that compares colors from webcam feed

Tags: library, c#, computer-vision, color

I want to write a program that can grab a frame from a webcam feed (usb webcam), takes a color sample from a specific coordinate, compares to a previous frame or specified color, and then takes an action if the color has left a threshold. Are there any good libraries for this or can this be done natively in C#?

While this is not its purpose, this program would be able to take the feed from a stationary webcam that looks at a traffic light and could tell me what state the trafic light is in.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you would need a library for, since it would probably be only a couple dozen lines of code.

Comment: Ah, I was looking through someones C++ project and they used OpenCV to do what I want to do and thought I needed something similar. If I could do it without fancy addons that is always a plus!

Comment: Check out the linux program `motion` and its source (C++ IIRC), you may be able to use some of it, just follow the GPL